# Restricting number of devices on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I'm working on a rails project and I would ideally like to restrict each user to only be able to access my application with 2 devices (in order to limit username & password sharing). I am currently using Devise for user authentication. I've researched this through SO and the Devise documentation, but haven't found any solutions yet. Surely I can't be the first person with this need. Anyone have any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with storing your device unique id in database.

Create a separate table where you can store your logged in device id and check when authentication.

For a hardware dependent identification key, we can also use a MAC address.

> A Media Access Control address (MAC address) is a unique identifier
>   assigned to network interfaces for communications on the physical
>   network segment. MAC addresses are most often assigned by the
>   manufacturer of a network interface card (NIC) and are stored in its
>   hardware, the card's read-only memory, or some other firmware
>   mechanism. [wikipedia]

Here is a gem for finding mac address:

```
https://github.com/ahoward/macaddr
```